# Google Analytics versus Clickmeter data

Tags: google-analytics

what is difference between unique referrals on Clickmeter and New users on Google Analytics? One of our vendor is using Clickmeter and we are using Google Analytics and the data doesn't match. Any suggestions on tracking unique referrals on Google Analytics?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0):

In **ClickMeter** a click is unique if is human (it does NOT come from a bot/spider) and if there are no clicks on the same link from the same IP in the 30 mins before this click was made. More info here: https://blog.clickmeter.com/click-types

**GA** determines unique using cookies (a completely different technique). In order for Google Analytics to determine which traffic belongs to which user, a unique identifier associated with each user is sent with each hit. track all the visits to a specific website https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en.

Moreover, GA analyzes all user on a specific website in the same bucket while ClickMeter performs a different count per each link. It may happen that more ClickMeter links point to the same site and a user that click two or three links together is counted as unique three times.

Please keep in mind that GA and ClickMeter are NOT the same thing and are used (together or not) for different reasons. https://blog.clickmeter.com/google-analytics-alternative